# I find a pdf with beautiful text font and math font, how to set in Latex to get these fonts

Tags: fonts

In pdf https://ora.ox.ac.uk/catalog/uuid:b64024da-8868-4353-9adb-8250ccd1e8b3/download_file?file_format=application%2Fpdf&safe_filename=Ricci%2BFlow%2Bin%2BMilnor%2BFrames%2B%2B%28Thesis%29.pdf,

I find it with beautiful text font and math font, how to set in Latex to  get these fonts.

Comment: It looks like the standard computer modern. Is there something in particular that you wonder about? (The interline spacing is to my taste too large.)

Comment: This is Computer Modern (or a successor). This font is distributed by each TeX distribution and it is set as default font. Nothing special.

Comment: `pdffonts` states that the document is using computer modern, mnsymbol (which probably should not be used with computer modern),  and `rsfs`

Comment: Welcome to the site! Nice question, but I’m going to mark it as a duplicate so readers who find it in a search will get a link to the answers that have already been written.